# How to keep new players following the questline?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, curse-of-strahd

Recently I've started DMing a premade campaign (Curse of Strahd) for 4 players and I'm having issues keeping them along the pre-made questline.

I've been playing an official campaign to practice being a better DM but its very hard to rein the players to follow the questline because they continually get distracted. They are having issues following the questline because they don't seem to see the big hints that are given out to send them to the next stage of the quest and then get focused on something pretty much unrelated like a alter or something just put in as decoration. Three of the players are quite new so I'm not sure if it's my DMing or how new they are.

How could I make the game easier for new players to follow while not oversimplifying it?

Comment: @NautArch I seen that question and I believe the answers don't answer my question

Comment: oh I'll try to provide more clarity

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of two questions which should provide detailed answers to your problem.

Comment: Also related: [How do I get the PCs to stop focusing on a red herring?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/7686)

Comment: Also, "How could I make the game easier for new players to follow while not oversimplifying it?" is an entirely different question from everything else, I'm not sure how it's even related.

Comment: I had it phrased wrong so it wasn't focusing on what I really wanted answered. Is the question easier to understand? I still believe the questions that are possible duplicates aren't actually answering the question I would like answered. I understand it's probably my fault the question isn't able to be figured out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142678/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-argo).

Comment: I think this question could work if you framed it specifically for Curse of Strahd, with information such as:
 - do you play this campaign "vanilla"? (including death house), if not, what are the modifications?
 - what did exactly the PC do, and why do you think they are not "following the questline"?

Comment: Is Curse of Strahd really a new-player quest line?

Comment: @CGCampbell The reason for my previous comment is that, from my point of view, the "quest-line" barely exists in this campaign. There are a ton of details, but most of them can be skipped: this isn't an issue. The truly important ones that make this adventure what it is aren't subtle, or take enough time to come up that I doubt OP has reached this point yet.